# Use values (integers) returned in JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

Im having issues with being able to get the indivisual responses from this JSON Array. Im trying to write some code that will allow me to use the vaules indivisually, as well as how to combine them if i needed too. These responses are always integers.

Java

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
data_array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

  for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {

      JSONObject prod = data_array.getJSONObject(i);
          Log.d("Logging Response", prod);
}
```

Json

```
[5652,8388,8388,7537,8843,2039,8235,0,12220]
```

I'd like to figure out how i can add them together and return the calculated result, as well as how to use them individually. such as (prod + prod + prod) etc...

Comment: you are getting `[5652,8388,8388,7537,8843,2039,8235,0,12220]` String in Response or it is inside inner JSONObject of JSONArray?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get you right, your question is about to iterate over an array or product? In this case you can use a "for (var n in yourObject)".

Comment: do you want to put that json array data in to a new json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    Integer prod = (Integer) data.get(i);
    System.out.println("Prod " + prod);
    // loop and add it to array or arraylist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the jsonarray as the response

```
ArrayList<Integer> jsonvalue=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {

      int i=     data_array.getInt(i);
jsonValue.add(i)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(jsonObj.getString(i));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To put that json array data in to a new json object, try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
data_array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject prod;

for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
  prod.put(i,data_array.getJSONObject(i));
      Log.d("Logging Response", prod);
}
```